# mysql select distinct in a select

Tags: mysql, subquery, distinct

When I write :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `codeArticle`
 FROM hs 
 WHERE `dateFacture` BETWEEN '2017-01-01'  AND '2017-12-31' 
 AND `codefamilleArticle` = 'COT'
```

I get a good answer :

codeArticle
COTFPR2017
COTFP2017
COTE2017
COTB2017
COTAP2018
COTAPR2018
COTJ2017
COTAB2018
COTAJ2018
COTAE2018

But I want to have some details about this list and I write :

```
SELECT codefamilleArticle,codeArticle,article 
FROM hs 
WHERE codeArticle = ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT codeArticle 
    FROM hs 
    WHERE dateFacture BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    AND codefamilleArticle = 'COT'
)
```

Then an error occurs and I get :

MySQL a répondu: Documentation

## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use IN

```
SELECT codefamilleArticle,codeArticle,articleFROM hs WHERE codeArticle IN ( SELECT DISTINCT codeArticle FROM hs WHERE dateFacture BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' AND codefamilleArticle = 'COT')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `= ANY` or `IN`:

```
SELECT codefamilleArticle,codeArticle,article
FROM hs
WHERE codeArticle = ANY (SELECT codeArticle -- DISTINCT in not needed
                         FROM hs
                         WHERE dateFacture BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
                           AND codefamilleArticle = 'COT')
```

Comment: IN runs ; ANY is not recognize by mysql. Thanks

Comment: IN is simply an alias for = ANY for subqueries. Hope both will work

Comment: @Chamarejc `=ANY` is supported by MySQL

Comment: =ANY runs but not ANY. 
There is an other difficulty : hope 10 answers, get more than 1000. Something is wrong in the request.

Comment: @Chamarejc Please read once again my answer. There is no instance of using **only** `ANY`. I specified exactly `= ANY`.